# Java combining two text files

Tags: java

I have an assignment for my Java class which asks me to combine two text files.

This is the code I have up until now.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CombineTwoFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        try
        {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "A.txt"));
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "B.txt"));
            String s1 =null;
            String s2 = null;

            while ((s1 = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                list.add(s1);        
            }
            while((s2 = r.readLine()) != null)
            {
                list.add(s2);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedWriter writer=null;
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("B.txt"));
        String listWord;              
        for (int i = 0; i< list.size(); i++)
        {
            listWord = list.get(i);
            writer.write(listWord);
            writer.write("\n");
        }
        System.out.println("completed");
        writer.close();    
    }
}
```

Now, when I compile it, i receive this message.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: A.txt (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
at CombineTwoFile.main(CombineTwoFile.java:15)
completed
```

I am using Coderunner on an Apple computer and i thought perhaps writing the text files as "C:/Users/dell/Desktop/Test/input1.txt" may fix the problem, however i am unsure on how to write that to correspond to my hard drive. Thanks for taking a look and i appreciate any help.

Comment: You need the full path to your files. `new FileReader( "A.txt")` will try to read the files from your classpath.

Comment: The file `A.txt` either doesn't exist or is in the wrong place. You can find where to put the file by logging the following value: `new File("A.txt").getCanonicalPath()`.

Comment: Just add the A.txt file to a directory and inside new FileReader( "A.txt")) instead of passing only "A.txt", pass as argument the full path to the A.txt file.  Example if you put your file A.txt in a temp folder in C drive.  you will pass as argument C:\\temp\\A.txt.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things that could be improved here.

First, as others have pointed out, you need to specify the correct path to the file, the way you're doing it assumes that the files are in the classpath, and apparently they are not.

You can either specify the absolute path, or the relative path compared to the class.

If you want to leave it as is, you're gonna need to put the file in the `classpath` (where your class runs).

See this for additional info on `absolute` and `relative path`:

http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/what-is-the-difference-between-absolute-relative-and-canonical-path-of-file-or-directory/60

Other than that, you shouldn't be throwing an Exception from `main`, instead, you should handle it.

I also suggest you use the new `try-with-resources`.

**Example:**

```
try(BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "C:\\Users\\...\\A.txt"));){

    //do something

} catch(IOException e){

    //handle

}

//no need to close the streams, the jgc will handle that for you
```

This will close the streams for you when you're done using them, inside of the try block.

If your teacher (as you added in one comment) wants you to be able to dynamically select a path, you're gonna need to enter it from the console and use that as an absolute path.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
String path = s.readLine(); //use this as absolute path
```

If you need to do it from a `GUI`, you're gonna need a `JFileChooser`.

As far as writing goes, the same suggestions apply.

You could also avoid writing line + '\n' by using a [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html). 
It will provide a println(String s) method, auto-flush, and it's better for portability reasons.

As a *minor* note, in this case you do not actually need `s2`, using `s1` again would do just fine.

Comment: No problem. I edited and added a few more suggestions, including the use of a PrintWriter.

Answer (score 0):

Your Java program could not find 'A.txt' at desired location, to know where to put you file you can use `system.getproperty( user.dir )` to know where system is looking for file. Other way is you can write absolute path in `new File('c:\\something\\A.txt');`

Hope it helps

Comment: Im in class right now, and my professor said not to include to absolute path because she'll just place all the files into one folder and test it. Any other possible solutions? Or perhaps is there a simple solution as to "placing the txt file at the desired location?" Not quite sure where it's looking. I also tried opening the txt files within my coding application

Comment: use System.out.println(system.getproperty( user.dir )); to see working directory, infact place the text file at same place as that of java file, and the file address will be something like "system.getproperty( user.dir )"+"A.txt"..Hope you get it

Comment: you can also use "System.out.println(new File("A.txt").getCanonicalPath());" to see where to put file, but above method is more appropriate for assignments.

Comment: Just add the A.txt and B.txt files to your current directory where you are executing your files within your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Lucas, your program is absolutely right. you don't need to correct anything just create a file "A.txt" manually, then run this code again.

Answer (score 0):

just place

`System.out.println(new File("A.txt").getCanonicalPath());`

before

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "A.txt"));

BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( "B.txt"));
```

you will get the exact path before the exception information like:

```
C:\Users\PiyushMittal\Downloads\Java-mongodb-hello-world-example\mongodb\A.txt
java.io.FileNotFoundException: A.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
completed   at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at com.mkyong.core.CombineTwoFile.main(CombineTwoFile.java:19)
```

and very first line is the place where you have to put the file :)